# Finch obstacle sensors is not working in java

Tags: java, robotics, finch

I am new to finch and Java code and I'm trying to make finch moves either left or right by its sensors. Hopefully someone can help.

```
if(suzie.isFinchLevel()) {
        suzie.saySomething("Moving forward");
        suzie.sleep(1000);
        while (!suzie.isObstacle()){
        suzie.setWheelVelocities(100,100);
        if(suzie.isObstacleLeftSide()){ //turn right
            suzie.setWheelVelocities(100,0,2000);
        }
        else if (suzie.isObstacleRightSide()){
            suzie.setWheelVelocities(0,100,2000); //turn left
        }   
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have not actually accessed the vlaues of the sensors. Remember the you must first access the values (via the getObstacleSensors(); method) of the sensors. Also recall that this method returns the value of each sensor as a boolean array. See the javadoc:

getObstacleSensors public boolean[] getObstacleSensors()

Returns the value of both obstacle sensors as 2 element boolean array. The left sensor is the 0th element, and the right sensor is the 1st element.

Returns: The values of left and right obstacle sensors in a 2 element array

---

I did something recently similar to what you're trying to do using input from the button actionlisteners. Before implementing it, I wrote a method called "obstacleAvoidance" that the bot would actually execute when an obstacle is encountered; this method accepts a Finch object (i.e. suzie) as an argument. This made the code [relatively] less cluttered. The code to perform this task (in the action listener) could appear something like this:

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

```
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    //Get the finchbot's obstacle sensors and store them in an array
    boolean [] sensors = suzie.getObstacleSensors();

    //Check to see if either of the ficnhbot's sensors 
    //detect an obstacle. This is enclosed in a while loop which is
    //broken if either sensor returns false (detects an obstacle)
    while (sensors [0] == false && sensors[1] == false)
    {
    // Sets the Action text field
   System.out.println( "Performing Action..." );

    // This method tells the robot to perform an action
    command.performAction(suzie, -255, -85);
    }

    //Otherwise, perform obstacle avoidance maneuver
    command.obtacleAvoidance(suzie);
}
```

}

I hope this serves as a good starting point for you...

T